# Why is the reflection operation on a planar molecule different from identity?

Tags: group-theory, quantum-chemistry

Consider the Ethylene molecule $C_2 H_4$ on teh $OXY$ plane.

[image: ethylene molecule]

The reflection operation $\sigma (xy)$ is considered different from the identity E (both being symmetry operations). I don't understand why: each atom stays in its original place...
Obviously, my question extends to any planar molecule.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please specify what exactly you mean by "is considered differently". Of course, they are, in general, two different operations, so they are distinguishable. If they are both part of the symmetry group, then the molecule stays invariant under both - but that does only make their effect the same in this specific case ...

Comment: Thank you :). My problem is: I wouldn't say they are distinguishable, exactly because their effect is the same.
 By "is considered different" I mean that both transformations appear in the symmetry group of this molecule. I was expecting them to be "the same operation", in the same sense as a rotation of $2\pi$ and another one of $4/pi$ (about a certain axis) are also the same operation...

Comment: (of course, I meant $4\pi$. The website does not let me edit my comment).

Comment: If you do not distinguish them because their action is different *for this molecule*, the symmetry group will always only have one element. Thus, it becomes useless as a characterisation. The difference to $2 \pi$ and $4 \pi$ rotations is that these are *always* the same on *any* molecule.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you for the answer, that makes sense. (I would up-vote it, but I don't think I can up-vote comments...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself using what Sanya said in the comment section above.

Although $\sigma (xy)$ leaves planar molecules (which lie in the $Oxy$ plane) untouched, that does not mean that  $\sigma (xy)$ is the same operation as the identity $E$. All it means is that both  $\sigma (xy)$ and $E$ are symmetry operations of our molecule.

For  $\sigma (xy)$ and $E$ to be equal they would have to have the same image for all objects (*i.e.* they would be the same mapping). This happens, for instance, with $E$ and the rotations of $2\pi$ (around some axis), which are thus considered to be the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

I general for a planar molecule, the reflection operation changes the relative positions of the atoms: you can easily see this by labeling the H atoms. $H_1 ... H_4$. By contrast a $2\pi$ rotation puts "everything back how it was". So while it may not matter for this molecule, it does matter for planar molecules in general.

Comment: The reflection operator _on the Oxy plane_  ($\sigma (xy)$) does not change the relative positions of atoms.